# SSRS data source connection error

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I've just updates a working report where I had to change the location of the database, it should work fine as I've changed it everywhere it needs to be changed I'm sure but I get this when I try run it

> The report server cannot process the report. The data source connection information has been deleted. (rsInvalidDataSourceReference)

I've check the data source and it is correct so what could it be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. 
The data source was not set to the right value. After changing it (inside the Report properties) everything worked fine.

Comment: @Axle It would be good if you actually explained how you did it. This answer is pretty useless to me.